# Install MySQL v8 in Google Colab. Service is not starting. Not recognised

Tags: mysql, google-colaboratory

I have been successfully installing and using MySQL V5.7 in Google Colab (with Ubuntu 18.04) for quite some time. However trying to install MySQL V8 has repeated failed. I have used the following sequence of commands ..

```
!apt update
!apt upgrade
#!wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
!wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb
!dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.*
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt install mysql-server
```

During the install, I provide the root password and have used both the strong password option as well as the legacy authentication. Everything goes fine upto this point and even the following command

```
!mysqld --version
```

returns the correct version

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.28 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

After this things go wrong! The MySQL service should have started but it hasn't

```
!mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

and when I try to start it, it is not recognised ( **neither mysql nor mysqld**)

```
!sudo service mysqld start
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

in fact, even this fails

```
!systemctl status mysql
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

What am I doing wrong? or what else should I do? or is it that for some reason, Google Colab  with Ubuntu 18.04 does not support MySQL V8

Comment: Please share snip from /var/log/mysqld.log to understand what is happening.

Comment: It would be best ( and easier)  if you click on this link get the Google Colab notebook and execute the commands  yourself ...  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PQyLADybom7EYGX4qV6h7a3wbDW-bVi7?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

No action required ... just this will do

```
!apt update > null
!apt -y install mysql-server -V 
!/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

then check

```
!mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

earlier this used to show Ver 5.7!
Now, with this we can now use CTE, recursion and Windows functions of v8

Answer (score 0):

Check with `sudo service mysql start` or `sudo start mysql` once.

Another thing is that google colab instance might not use the system init system at all. That's why it's resulting in `System has not been booted with systemd as init system`. Check with the sys-v init system once. Its commands look like `service service_name start`. The same thing happens when trying to start services in WSL.

Comment: !sudo mysqld --user=root start ... worked without any errors but then again, it failed to connect. Can you please check the Colab notebook given in the main question